# Assuming AD, is every infinite cardinal closed under power set in a choice model?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, determinacy

Assume AD+DC. Assume $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal and $N$ is a (set or class) transitive model of ZFC containing $\kappa$.

Is it true that for all $\alpha<\kappa$, $N$ thinks that the power set of $\alpha$ has size less than $\kappa$?

This seems like obvious, at least for $\kappa<\Theta$, but I don't find a reference or an idea yet.

Comment: So... every cardinal is strongly inaccessible in any inner model of $\sf ZFC$?

Comment: If so, every regular cardinal is strongly inaccessible in any inner model of 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some partial answers:

(1) Under the (possibly) additional assumption of $\mathsf{AD}^+$ we can prove the weaker conclusion that $\alpha^{+N} < \alpha^+$ for every infinite ordinal $\alpha < \Theta$:

- Assume toward a contradiction that $\alpha^{+N} = \alpha^+$ and use $\mathsf{AC}$ in $N$ to take a sequence of functions $(f_\xi : \xi < \alpha^+)$ such that each function $f_\xi$ is a surjection from $\alpha$ onto $\xi$.  This shows that $\alpha^+$ is regular in $V$; otherwise we could combine cofinally many of these surjections to get a surjection from $\alpha \times \alpha$ to $\alpha^+$, a contradiction.
- By a theorem of Woodin every uncountable regular cardinal less than $\Theta$ is measurable (as stated by Koellner and Woodin, [Large cardinals from determinacy](http://logic.harvard.edu/koellner/LCFD.pdf), p. 12,) so $\alpha^+$ is measurable.  But then we can take an ultrapower of the sequence $(f_\xi : \xi < \alpha^+)$ to again get a surjection from $\alpha$ to $\alpha^+$, a contradiction.

(2) Under the stronger assumption of $\mathsf{AD} + V = L(\mathbb{R})$ we have $(2^\alpha)^N < \alpha^+$ for every infinite ordinal $\alpha < \Theta$, which implies the desired conclusion.  This follows directly from Steel, [An outline of inner model theory](http://math.berkeley.edu/~steel/papers/steel1.pdf), Theorem 8.26, which says that for every infinite cardinal $\alpha < \Theta$, every wellordered family of subsets of $\alpha$ has cardinality at most $\alpha$.
Steel calls this result the "boldface $\mathsf{GCH}$ for $L(\mathbb{R})$" and proves it from $\mathsf{GCH}$ in $\text{HOD}_x$ where $x$ is a real, which can be understood as a fine-structural model.

Note that the theorem that every uncountable regular cardinal less than $\Theta$ is measurable was first proved under the hypothesis $\mathsf{AD} + V = L(\mathbb{R})$ also using fine structure (see Steel, Theorem 8.27) before being generalized to the $\mathsf{AD}^+$ setting by Woodin.  I don't know whether we should expect a similar generalization of the boldface $\mathsf{GCH}$.

(3) For cardinals $\kappa = \alpha^+ > \Theta$, even the weaker statement $\alpha^{+N} < \alpha^+$ can fail.  Consider the case that $V = L(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$, $\mathsf{AD}^+ + \mathsf{AD}_\mathbb{R}$ holds, and $N = \text{HOD}$.  We can add $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ back to $\text{HOD}$ by a Vopěnka-type forcing of cardinality $\Theta$; this argument is due to Woodin and is written up in Section 4.3.4.2 of Nam Trang's [thesis](http://math.cmu.edu/~namtrang/thesis.pdf). This forcing doesn't collapse cardinals above $\Theta$, so $\alpha^{+N} = \alpha^+ = \kappa$.

Comment: If you work in $V=L(\mathcal P(\Bbb R))$ which does not satisfy choice; I don't see how you can add $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ into $\rm HOD$ without either adding new sets to $V$ or violating the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Asaf You are right; I was being imprecise.  The generic filter does not live in $V$, but the extension of $\text{HOD}$ by this generic filter is precisely $V$.

Comment: But any extension of $\rm HOD$ by a generic filter will satisfy choice, so it couldn't possibly be $V$.

Comment: @Asaf Oops, today I am not very good at saying things that are literally true.  $V$ is a symmetric submodel of the generic extension of $\text{HOD}$.

Comment: Okay, I am willing to buy that. Although I don't see an immediate proof.

Comment: @Asaf It's not obvious.  It's due to Woodin and is written up in Section 4.3.4.2 of Nam Trang's [thesis](http://math.cmu.edu/~namtrang/thesis.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Some parts which are "clear" in the proof are not so clear to me. Maybe because I don't know enough about determinacy related topics; or maybe because I've felt that a lot of arguments about iterations and symmetries felt obvious to me, but ended up being flatly false without many additional assumptions. But I'm more than willing to take this proof for granted.

Comment: Okay, I reviewed that proof again; and I'm still not clear as to what "*the symmetric part of ...*" means. Is this standard terminology in $\sf AD$ related topics?

Comment: @Asaf I think "$\mathcal{H}^+(\Gamma)$ is the symmetric part of $\mathcal{H}^+[G]$" in that context means that $\mathcal{H}^+(\Gamma)$ is the class of sets that are definable in $\mathcal{H}^+[G]$ from parameters in $\mathcal{H}^+$ and in $\Gamma$, or equivalently (I hope) from parameters in $\mathcal{H}^+$ and some "proper initial segment" of $G$ in some sense.  We usually think of symmetric models in terms of definability, or at least I do.  I need to take a closer look at that proof myself, and I hope to do this within the next few days.

Comment: So $(2^\alpha)^N<\alpha^{+}$ for all $\alpha<\Theta^{L(\mathbb{R})}$ by Moschovakis coding lemma. With HOD computation, boldface GCH below $\Theta$ holds. Possibly it could be proved from $\text{AD}^+$ alone.

Comment: @Yizheng Possibly; one option would be to ask Hugh if his methods will work to prove it from $\mathsf{AD}^+$.